# Rails still throwing error for page that doesn't exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used to have a class Uploads that I later decided to delete. I ran a migration to drop the table, made sure my schema was updated, manually deleted the associated views and controllers, etc. I even ran a grep through my directory to check for traces of "upload" or references to it. However, when I try to access my page I get an error in the console -- 500 Service Error. the log says:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template /app\views\upload\uploadfile.rhtml with     {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/claire/Documents/folio/app/views"
  * "/Users/claire/Documents/folio"
  * "/"
):
  app/controllers/upload_controller.rb:3:in `index'
```

...But neither of those documents exist anymore. I tried clearing my cache and cookies an it has the same effect. What could be causing this?!

My routes.rb file

```
Folio::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :projects

  #get "home/index"
  root :to => "projects#new"
  match 'project/new',:controller=>"projects",:action=>"create"
  match "project/:id", :controller => "projects", :action=>"download"
  match "projects_controller/filter_list", :controller => "projects", :action => "filter_list"
end
```

Comment: Are we talking about developer mode or production? Did you restart the server?

Comment: Developer mode, I think. I'm just viewing it on Localhost. how do I restart the server?

Comment: Whats in app/controllers/upload_controller.rb:3?  Just stop webrick or whichever server you are using and start it again to pick the new file changes or new routes

Comment: Restarted the server and it didn't help. Line 2 of upload_controller (which is in the trash is: render => 'app/views/upload'.

Comment: I should add..I think I started noticing this problem after I ran bundle exec rake assets:precompile yesterday. I tried running it again though and I get the same error.

Comment: Does `upload_controller.rb` exist or not?  It sure looks like it does from that log entry, with a line number and everything.  You might try:  `rake assets:clean tmp:clear assets:precompile`.

Comment: Are you looking at a current log file?

Comment: jordanpg: no, it doesn't exist; that command didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your routes file? I think the problem is that you still have routes pointing to the deleted controller.